# Telnet server always returns garbage when connecting to it using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, telnet

So I am trying to make a telnet client that connects to some address part for work and part for `Boost::Asio` learning purpose.

My small project has three handlers:

Resolve handler:

```
void resolverHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter) {
    if (ec) {
        cout << "Resolved failed with message: " << ec.message() << endl;
    }
    else {
        ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iter;
        cout << "Connection to: " << endpoint.address() << ":" << endpoint.port() << endl;
        tcpSocket.async_connect(endpoint, connectHandler);
    }
}
```

Connect handler

```
   void connectHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        if (ec) {
            cout << "Connect failed with message: " << ec.message() << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Connection established" << endl;
            tcpSocket.async_read_some(buffer(_data), readHandler);
        }
    }
```

Read handler:

```
void readHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t amountOfBytes) {
    if (ec) {
        cout << "Read failed with message: " << ec.message() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << amountOfBytes << endl;
        cout << _data.data() << endl;
        tcpSocket.async_read_some(buffer(_data), readHandler);
    }
}
```

And this is my main function:

```
io_service ioservice;
ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioservice);
ip::tcp::socket tcpSocket(ioservice);
array<char, 16> _data;
ip::tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.200.200", "23");
  

int main() {

    resolver.async_resolve(query, resolverHandler);

    ioservice.run();

    return 0;
}
```

But I always get garbage like this:

```
Connection to: 192.168.206.226:23
Connection established
15
 ² ²  ²# ²' ²$
```

I admit that I am new to telnet, but I am not sure why do I get this response ? Not sure if I need to null terminate the data that I receive before printing it, but even like that I have the same response.

Here is the normal response I should receive - tried with Windows Telnet:

```
Welcome Message (localhost) (ttyp0)

login:
```

Apreciate if someone has any ideas on what to do.

Comment: Please read more about [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), reads its RFC's and learn about option negotiation. Telnet is not a simple plain-text protocol, but rather a statefull protocol which can transmit binary (non-text) message sequences.

Comment: If you treat the bytes you read as numbers and not characters when you print them, I bet you'll find it's a bunch of telnet protocol codes. `IAC WILL FOO` and the like.

Comment: @Shawn: great point, now it makes more sense :)